Busboy NOT Working with Firebase/Firestorage
For the past 6 weeks I have tried probably every way to upload an image to firebase using Firebase-Admin, Nodejs, Busboy and Multer but no to avail.
I even tried to get the help of ChatGPT extension Grimoire and even that couldn't solve the problem!
Always getting the same exact error:
Error uploading: Error: Unexpected end of form
>      at Multipart._final (/Users/user/Desktop/project-Functions/functions/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17)
>      at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:906:14)
>      at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:920:5)
>      at Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:835:5)
>      at onend (node:internal/streams/readable:946:10)
>      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
>    storageErrors: []

My code relatively looks like this, although there were many other ways that I tried but they all look pretty much the same:
app.post("/uploadProfilePicture", upload.single("profileImage"), (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    const { originalname, buffer } = file;
    const blob = bucket.file("profile_pictures/" + originalname);
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: file.mimetype,
        },
    });

    blobStream.on("error", (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res
            .status(500)
            .send({ message: "Failed to upload image.", error: err.toString() });
    });

    blobStream.on("finish", () => {
        const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`;
        res
            .status(200)
            .send({ message: "Image uploaded successfully", url: publicUrl });
    });

    blobStream.end(buffer);
});


Your question should include everything we need to duplicate the issue, including how you are making the request to this function.

through postman my friend, the rest of the code is simple, using express... like not sure what more you need/.

Show or explain your use of postman.  We should be able to duplicate the issue using the instructions you provide.  For all we know, you could be using postman incorrectly, but without seeing that, we'll never know.

I've been a developer for 8years. I can guarantee you that I'm using postman the way it should. I don't change any of the automatic headers, body is form-data with key(file) and uploaded file.
I can almost guarantee you that if you tried to use my code above or even code it yourself (using firebase-admin not regular firebase) it will most likely fail.

After doing more research it seems like its an issue with busboy as to how its receiving the files, don't know if they had some kind of update but even with multer all issues lead back to busboy
